# How to make WordPress running at Google Cloud Platform more secure?

Tags: wordpress, security, ssh

So, I have an instance created at Google Cloud Platform, with Bitnami WordPress installed, and my website got hacked...again. I migrated a few months ago from my hosting to GCP, thinking it will be safer, because my website got hacked before, probably by my competitors, because I have several more websites and only this one gets hacked. But the migration didn't help. I thought Google took security more seriously. I don't know if the instance got hacked, or WordPress, or something else. So, what can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Security of your VM, OS, and WordPress are [your responsibility](https://www.cisecurity.org/blog/shared-responsibility-cloud-security-what-you-need-to-know/).

There are a zillion ways to get hacked. Your question has no details on how your systems are configured, what hack occurred, etc.

The Internet has many tutorials on [securing Linux](https://securityboulevard.com/2020/08/linux-server-security-10-linux-hardening-security-best-practices/), [securing WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/), [securing Google Cloud](https://medium.com/@doctusoft/how-to-make-your-google-cloud-platform-project-more-secure-an-introduction-8d35e25a8a33). [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=securing%20linux) also has good resources to learn from. Invest the time to learn how security works and how to protect yourself.

Regarding your competitors hacking you - maybe if they are naive or unethical. In general, it is often easy to figure out who did what, when, and from where. The experts that know how to cover their tracks won't target your site as there are no financial or bragging rights. Most likely a [script kiddie](https://www.hypr.com/script-kiddie/) found an easy target.